# Get the 1st date of every month & year and the corresponding value

Tags: mysql, grouping

i have a table records with the following columns and data-

```
Date        |   Value

01-01-2008      3040

02-01-2008      3940

03-01-2008      4240

01-03-2008      5340

01-04-2008      5540

01-05-2008      4340

04-09-2009      7800

'

'

31-12-2013      4350
```

The dates range from 1st Jan 2008 to 31st Dec 2013 with corresponding values against.

is there any mysql statement i can write which can get me the 1st date of of year month and the corresponding value.

something like -

```
 01-01-2008 3040
 01-02-2008 corresponding value
 01-03-2008 corresponding value
```

for each month of each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the first day for every month in database you can use [*`day()`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) function

```
select *
from table
where  day(`Date`)  = 1
```

According to your format i suspect you have stored dates as strings in varchar field then  your may need [*`str_to_date()`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it to real date object

```
select *
from table
where  day(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d-%m-%Y'))  = 1
```

[Sample demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f62f25/5)

**Edit from comments**

If you want to find the minimum date per month,year group you can use a self join by using date value and grouping by month and year

```
select *
from test t
join (
     select min(`Date`) `Date`
      from test 
     group by month(`Date`),
              year( `Date`)
    ) t1
on(t.`Date` = t1.`Date`)
```

[Sample Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a8f8e/1) *i have update some data in fiddle to better analyze*

Comment: The date is a datestamp and the min date may not always be 01. I am able to get the 1st date my using min(date) but do not have a clue how to get the corresponding value data for each min date.

Comment: @Khalid Junaid- Thanks mate, this give results as i need

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if there is a date-based answer for this
i mean to handle the `Date` as a DataType, but if you convert the date to String
then all dates (strings) starts with **01-** will be the rows you need. (if the date format is d-m-y)

```
select * from mytable where DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%d-%m-%Y') like '01-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 SELECT t.date , t.value FROM table t WHERE DAYOFMONTH(date)=1;
```